# python - how pass user input variable between strings

Tags: python-2.7

Just learning python and stuck on basic problem. I have several functions, the first takes the name of a file from user input. The second function should take the file that was given in openFile and count characters, however I keep having to reenter the file name again in the charcount function. Since I'm still new, just looking for the most basic solution to not reenter file name in second function. Thanks

```
def openFile():
    user_inp = raw_input(str(" "))
    myfile = user_inp
    fhandle = open(myfile,'r')
    return fhandle


def charcount():
    file1 = openFile()
    charcount = 0
    line = file1.readline()
    while line != "":
        charcount = charcount + len(line)
        line = file1.readline()
    file1.close()
    return(charcount)
```

Comment: charcount() calls openFile() so there's no need to call it on its own first.

Comment: Thanks, so the first function is to get the input of a filename, as 2-3 other functions will eventually need to use the filename or open file. When I input the file name in the first function I'm not expecting to have to input a file name again with the second function since its calling first function but for some reason I do.

Comment: It's because you're calling the first function, then you're calling the second function which calls the first function again.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user input outside of those two functions and then pass it into each of them as an argument when you need it.